# The easiest way to draw an image?

Tags: c++, graphics, image-processing

Assume you want to read an image file in a common file format from the hard drive, change the color of one pixel, and display the resulting image to the screen, in C++.

Which (open-source) libraries would you recommend to accomplish the above with the least amount of code?

Alternatively, which libraries would do the above in the most elegant way possible?

A bit of background: I have been reading a lot of computer graphics literature recently, and  there are lots of relatively easy, pixel-based algorithms which I'd like to implement. However, while the algorithm itself would usually be straightforward to implement, the necessary amount of frame-work to manipulate an image on a per-pixel basis and display the result stopped me from doing it.

Comment: The displaying alone will be a lot of code, and also system-dependent. Are you already using some GUI library? What platform are you using?

Comment: Martin: There is no source code yet. (Actually there is, but small enough that I wouldnt hesitate to restart from scratch)

Comment: It is the eternal C++ question.  Backed-up with 5 upvotes already.  After 20+ years of graphical user interfaces being mainstream, the core problem of showing an image still gasts the flabber of the practitioners of the language.  Not good.

Comment: @Hans: kind of, but then again not. The question is just which of the many available libraries are recommended. Is it a bad thing for the language to have multiple libraries available to provide GUI functionality?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) library is easy to use.

```
CImg<unsigned char> img("lena.png");              // Read in the image lena.png
const unsigned char valR = img(10,10,0,0);        // Read the red component at coordinates (10,10)
const unsigned char valG = img(10,10,0,1);        // Read the green component at coordinates (10,10)
const unsigned char valB = img(10,10,2);          // Read the blue component at coordinates (10,10) (Z-coordinate omitted here).
const unsigned char avg = (valR + valG + valB)/3; // Compute average pixel value.
img(10,10,0) = img(10,10,1) = img(10,10,2) = avg; // Replace the pixel (10,10) by the average grey value.
CImgDisplay main_disp(img, "Modified Lena");      // Display the modified image on the screen
img.save("lena_mod.png");                         // Save the modified image to lena_mod.png
```

It can also be used as a rather powerful image processing library. See the examples [here](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/screenshots.shtml).

Comment: For a simpler program ("with the least amount of code" was the request), do not display the image, just output the modified image, and use a separate image viewer program.

Comment: @Raedwald "and display the resulting image to the screen" <- that gives me the impression OP wants to launch an image viewer from the program. It's one line though, so no need to fret IMHO.

Comment: @Viet It uses ImageMagick, so yes.

Answer (score 5):

You should look into the OpenCV library, especially if you're doing theoretical research into computer graphics.

Comment: More luxurious alternative is Intel Performance Primitives library :)

Comment: +1 my choice, if you want more than a pixel.... @9dan for some reason, I thought OpenCV started from the Intel libraries... was I wrong about that?

Answer (score 0):

If target application is windows-only, you could use GDI+, described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/gdi/gdi/article.php/c3705) is one of many proofs of concept for image manipulation using GDI+.

EDIT: Library is not open sourced, included in OS since Windows XP (can be installed on 98 and 2000), API is publicly available, and it gives you many image processing functions at hand which could be used in more complicated algorithms.