# Draw simple png image from C++

Tags: c++, png

I want to create a png image from my C++ program (and save it to the disk). I need only the very basic operations such as draw line, draw circle, fill rectangle, fill circle, etc.. I want to use a very small (ideally 1 header and 1 source file) and developer friendly library what is open source and cross platform (Windows and Unix required).

I have found PNGwriter, but it isn't compiling for me under Ubuntu 12.04 with g++ 4.6.3 (linking problem) and require a lot of other library to be installed.

Which is the smallest library what meet this basic requirements?

Comment: linking problem - what's the error message? have you linked the library?

Comment: I compiled it with the following command:
`g++ pngw.cpp \`freetype-config --cflags\` -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lpng -lpngwriter -lz -lfreetype`
The first error message (I get several similar error): undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'

Comment: Might be utterly wrong but maybe `-lpngwriter -lpng` not `-lpng -lpngwriter`?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It gives exactly the same result.

Comment: @john: After I swap them, only one error remained:  undefined reference to `png_set_gray_1_2_4_to_8'

Comment: I'd recommend Qt, but it is not very small, very powerful and versatile though. Runs pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @SqrtPi This post might be relevant https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=89952 seems like its some version issue in libpng.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576182/the-easiest-way-to-draw-an-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say : The CImg Library (http://cimg.sourceforge.net) looks like the perfect library for you. It's just one header file and is template-based (but not *heavily*).
Very easy to use and it has methods as 'draw_line()', 'draw_circle()' and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use this library:

```
http://www.antigrain.com/
```

Comment: It is far more complicated than what I am looking for, but if there is no better solution, I will take a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV http://docs.opencv.org/index.html offers some basic drawing as well. Maybe not the smallest library, but widely used for image processing and well supported on windows and linux.