# C++ Recursive depth-first search maze algorithm and where to go now?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I've been making a attempt to work out a maze generator using a recursive depth first search style algorithm. I know it's been done many times in the past but for my own understanding I've been trying to implement it from scratch myself in order to better understand it.

So, this is my attempt so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unistd.h>

struct vertex {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Init the map
    int map_size = 24;
    int half_point = map_size / 2;

    int map[map_size+1][map_size+1];    

    for(int y = 0; y < map_size+1; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < map_size+1; x++) {
            map[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }

    vertex start;
    start.x = half_point;
    start.y = half_point;

    std::vector<vertex> history;

    // Set start point as visited
    history.push_back(start);
    while( !history.empty() ) {

        vertex v = history.back();

        map[v.x][v.y] = 1;

        // Calculate the directions for each vertex
        vertex N;        N.x = v.x+1;        N.y = v.y;
        vertex S;        S.x = v.x-1;        S.y = v.y;
        vertex E;     E.x = v.x;       E.y = v.y-1;
        vertex W;    W.x = v.x;     W.y = v.y + 1;

        bool can_north = false;  bool can_south = false;  bool can_east = false;   bool can_west = false;

        // Check north and add if relevant
        if( N.x >= 0 && N.x <= map_size && N.y >= 0 && N.y <= map_size && map[N.x][N.y] == 0 ) {  can_north = true; }
        // Check south and add if relevant
        if( S.x >= 0 && S.x <= map_size && S.y >= 0 && S.y <= map_size && map[S.x][S.y] == 0 ) {   can_south = true;   }
        // Check east and add if relevant
        if( E.x >= 0 && E.x <= map_size && E.y >= 0 && E.y <= map_size && map[E.x][E.y] == 0 ) {  can_east = true;  }
        // Check west and add if relevant
        if( W.x >= 0 && W.x <= map_size && W.y >= 0 && W.y <= map_size && map[W.x][W.y] == 0 ) {  can_west = true;  }

        std::vector<vertex> available;
        if(can_north) { available.push_back(N); }
        if(can_south) { available.push_back(S); }
        if(can_east) { available.push_back(E); }
        if(can_west) { available.push_back(W); }

        // Select random element from availables 
        if( !available.empty() )
        {
            std::random_shuffle( available.begin(), available.end() );
            vertex aV = available.back();

            history.push_back(aV);

            available.clear();
        } else {
            if( !history.empty() ) {
                history.pop_back();
            }
        }

        // Animate the output to the console
        system("clear");
        for(int y = 0; y < map_size+1; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < map_size+1; x++) {
                std::cout << map[x][y] << ", ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

        usleep(5000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's using a Linux system call in there to clear the terminal each time before displaying the update to have a basic animation of the paths it takes.

What I don't know and I trying to understand is...
1) Is this actually a recursive depth-first search algorithm?

If so, then at least I have understood the concept correctly.

2) How would I go about drawing this to an image file?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what do you want regarding drawing to an image file? Do you have a design in mind? Do you want an actual image format or do you simply want to dump the data in plain text format?

Comment: It's not recursive at all.

Comment: @Gernot1976 Simulated is different from actual recursive. Wherever recursive is mentioned, there usually needs to be a recursive function. and the whole point of implementing DFS recursive, is that you are relying on the recursive call stack instead of handling the stack yourself. This make the code simpler, thought it's not as efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your first question

> Is this actually a recursive depth-first search algorithm?

At the Recursive depth-first search algorithm each cell has on of three states (Unvisitied, Visit In Progress and Visitied). The idea is to traverse through a graph and visit each node. If a node has 'Unvisited' condition it becomes 'Visit In Progress' and each neighbor will be visited. After each neighbor was visited the node becomes 'Visited'. To do so you have to remember each cell in your maze you visited once and never travers it again. Each member of `history` full fill condition 'Visit In Progress', and each cell which is set in `map` full fill condition 'Visited'. My answer is: **Yes**.

Comment to your second question:

> How would I go about drawing this to an image file?

To draw an image I recommend you The [CImg](http://cimg.eu/) library. See more at question [The easiest way to draw an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576182/the-easiest-way-to-draw-an-image)

If you like to draw the traversed path you need a second stack or similar container where you record all the steps you have done. Perhaps you can draw a raster and arrows from one to an other cell for each step. If you draw arrows from north to south right shifted to them form south to north and those from east to west down shifted to them from west to east you won't have any overlapping.